# Core data prefilling sqlite db. What is Z_MAX?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, sqlitemanager

I am using the SQLite Manager extension to Firefox to prefill my core data sqlite database.

But when i try adding more to the prefilled database my app crashes. I suspect it has something to do with Z_MAX for my entity in the table Z_PRIMARYKEY.

What should i set Z_MAX to? Is it supposed to be the number of items in my entity?

So if i add 1000 entries in the table Z_MYENTITY then i have to set Z_MAX to the correspoding entity in Z_PRIMARYKEY to 1000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend not trying to replicate the internal structure of a Core Data database.  It is undocumented and not guaranteed by Apple to remain the same over time (even though it has been relatively stable).

Instead, I suggest creating a simple Mac client to prepopulate your database.  This is a very easy thing to do, as I described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248363/portability-of-core-datas-sqlite-file-between-os-x-and-iphone-os/2248463#2248463).  I also show how to do this in the video for the Core Data session of [my iPhone class on iTunes U](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-spring-2010/id407243032).

Comment: Thanks I'l whatch those iTunes U videos! Seems useful!

If changing the Z_MAX is not an option, I think I'l implement a method to parse my csv and add to the entity..

But I'l check you're method out first..

Comment: @Larsaronen - If you watch the video, you'll see me create a Mac client in under 15 minutes to do data entry for an iPhone Core Data application.  I'll think you'll find that a lot easier than spending hours to reverse engineer the database format.

Comment: I had a huge database in a spreadsheet, so a saving it as a csv and parsing that was easy and fast enough.. But thanx for pointing me to you're iTunes U videos. I'm sure they will be a great resource.